# SSH into raspberry with outside network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dhcp

I cannot find how to ssh into raspberry pi from the outside network. I have set up port forwarding, on port `80` for my raspberry pi. I have used https://httpbin.org/ip to obtain  the ip address of my computer. I have used DHCP to bind the MAC of my raspberrypi to a particular IP on my localhost, suppose it is: `192.168.0.111`.

When I access it locally, it is simply like: `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` and that is it. But how would I do it from outside network? How would I remotely ssh into it now? The following does not work:

`ssh pi@<myip> -p 80`

so if the ip from httpbin.org is 10.20.30.222, then I would do:

`ssh pi@10.20.30.222 -p 80`

It feels as if I'm not using the piece of information that is the highlighted part here: 192.168.0.**111**. Can someone please help me with the right syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Just substitute the external IP you got from httpbin.org and the forwarded port. Obviously, the external IP can't be 192.168.xxx.xxx.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow.

Comment: Suppose my external ip from httpbin.org is 10.20.30.222

Comment: ...then you'd do  `ssh pi@10.20.30.222 -p 80`. If it doesn't works, something is wrong with port forwarding.

Comment: let me try this again tomorrow. That is what I did initially. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The external port in this case should be port 80 and it should be forwarding to port 22 ip 192.168.0.111 (your Rpi IP address and default ssh port). You should configure all this on your home router.

Then you should be able to connect to your pi by doing:

`ssh pi@10.20.30.222 -p 80`

If you want to use port 80 in your raspberry then you can change the default ssh port on your RPi in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to port 80.

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks. I do not follow the part where you say that the external port should forwarding to port 22 ip 192.168.0.111

Comment: On your router look for port forwarding and set: External port 80 maps to port 22 IP 192.168.0.111. Then you should be able to do: `ssh pi@10.20.30.222 -p 80`. You router will forward incoming connections (to port 80 of your router) to port 22 of your RPi

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/6772/113479).  I will shortly rephrase a [very convenient solution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107310/113479) using [SSHHub](https://sshhub.de) (disclamer, I am the author).  It uses ssh's own forwarding to access your Rasperry PI from anywhere.  Its reliable, free and **pretty simple to setup**.  Register once:

```
ssh info@sshhub.de register
```

run on your Raspberry PI:

```
while true; do ssh [username]@sshhub.de -R 22:localhost:22 -N -o ServerAliveInterval=10; sleep 10; done
```

...and thats it!  You can connect your Raspberry Pi from anywhere:

```
ssh -J [username]@sshhub.de localhost
```